# Keeweb self-hosted getting Google hasn’t verified this app error #2018

Tags: google-oauth

Keeweb deployed as self hosted on kubernetes and integrated with gdrive but getting "Google hasn’t verified this app" error.

Nothing in log, follow steps - https://github.com/keeweb/keeweb#self-hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

means exactly that. An app was created on [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard). This app is being used to request consent of a user to access their data.  So a consent screen has been configured.

Any app which requests data of a user, and uses sensitive scopes will need to go though the verification process with google in order to be sure that the app is secure.

[Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)

> An unverified app is an app or Apps Script that requests a sensitive or restricted OAuth scope, but hasn't gone through the Google verification process. Users of unverified apps or your test builds might get warnings based on the OAuth scopes you're using. This is to protect users and their data from deceptive apps.